# How to get the CNN model size?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

https://keras.io/api/applications/#available-models

From the table given by Keras, we know Xception has 22,910,480 parameters in total, which is the number of weight and bias of convoluation and FC layers. How do we get the size of 88 MB from the number of parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every tf.float32 / tf.int32 takes 4 bytes. So 23 * 4 ~ 88. There could be some tf.float16, tf.int16.